# Почему при кратком синтаксисе при работе в цикле списка у меня другой результат чем при работе в обычном синтаксисе?

Tags: python

У меня есть список.

Вот пример:

```
ents = [nan, '27 December 2021', '27 June 2022', '27 December 2022', '27 June 2023', '26 December 2023', '25 June 2024 (the "Final Valuation Date")']
```

Мне необходимо удалить с каждого элемента списка выше, подстроки с других двух списков.

Вот эти списки:

```
right_content_list =[' (the "Final Valuation Date")']
left_content_list = []
```

Как видите второй список пустой.
Когда я удаляю подстроки по первому списку:

```
ents = [str(i).replace(j, "") for i in ents for j in right_content_list]
```

Я получаю тот результат, который я хочу:

```
ents = ['nan', '27 December 2021', '27 June 2022', '27 December 2022', '27 June 2023', '26 December 2023', '25 June 2024']
```

Но, когда я удаляю подстроки по второму списку (который пустой):

```
ents = [str(i).replace(j, "") for i in ents for j in left_content_list]
```

я получаю вот такой результат:

```
ents = []
```

Хотя я ожадаю, что мне вернется входящий список.

При чем, если я использую несокращенный формат работы со списками:

```
for j in left_content_list:
    ents = [str(i).replace(j, "") for i in ents]
```

Я получаю нужный мне результат и для второго списка:

```
ents = [nan, '27 December 2021', '27 June 2022', '27 December 2022', '27 June 2023', '26 December 2023', '25 June 2024 (the "Final Valuation Date")']
```

Вопросы:

1. Почему для пустого списка подстрок не работает сокращенный формат работы со списками?
2. Как это исправить?

Спасибо

Comment: что еще за  "сокращенный формат"? не надо изобретать терминологию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
for j in left_content_list:
    ents = [str(i).replace(j, "") for i in ents]
```

Если у вас список `left_content_list` пустой, то этот цикл просто не отработает ни разу, в `ents` останется тоже, что и было до выполнения этого цикла.

```py
ents = [str(i).replace(j, "") for i in ents for j in left_content_list]
```

Это **списочное сокращение** не эквивалентно вашему предыдущему коду. Оно эквивалентно следующему:

```py
ents_new = []
for i in ents:
    for j in left_content_list:
        ents_new.append(str(i).replace(j, ""))
ents = ents_new
```

Естественно, если в `left_content_list` пусто, то и результатом работы такого кода будет пустой список.